Why is ContextWrapper not applied?
Why is ContextWrapper not applied? There is not much to describe the problem, the wrapper does not apply to the Activity. I use Localize in my project, is there a problem with it?
class MainScreenActivity : BaseActivity() {
...
    override fun fetchStringResourceKeys(): Map<Int, String> {
        return ResourceKeys::class.java.fields.associate { field: Field -> 
            field.getInt(null) to field.name 
        }
    }

    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        val updatedThemeContext = newBase.getDependencies<MainActivityDependencies>()
            .themeManager
            .applyTheme(newBase)
        super.attachBaseContext(LocalizationContextWrapper.wrap(updatedThemeContext))
    }
...
}

abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
...
    abstract fun fetchStringResourceKeys(): Map<Int, String>

    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        val customContextWrapper = ResourceKeyContextWrapper(
            baseContext = newBase,
            stringResourceKeys = fetchStringResourceKeys(),
        )
        super.attachBaseContext(customContextWrapper)
    }
...
}

internal class ResourceKeyContextWrapper(
    baseContext: Context,
    private val stringResourceKeys: Map<Int, String>,
) : ContextWrapper(baseContext) {
    override fun getResources(): Resources {
        val originalResources = super.getResources()
        return CustomResources(
            originalResources = originalResources,
            stringResourceKeys = stringResourceKeys,
        )
    }
}

internal class CustomResources(
    originalResources: Resources,
    private val stringResourceKeys: Map<Int, String>,
) : Resources(originalResources.assets, originalResources.displayMetrics, originalResources.configuration) {

    override fun getString(@StringRes id: Int): String = 
        stringResourceKeys[id] ?: super.getString(id)

    override fun getString(@StringRes id: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any?): String {
        return stringResourceKeys[id] ?: super.getString(id, *formatArgs)
    }

    override fun getText(id: Int): CharSequence = 
        stringResourceKeys[id] ?: super.getText(id)
}

What I tried:
1. Completely removing the call from RootActivity.
2. Double-checking getStringResourceKeys (it returns everything correctly).
3. Calling the delegate for attachBaseContext2 and applying a wrapper to it.
4. Applying the wrapper to ApplicationContext, but I couldn’t retrieve the string keys.
5. Skipping the call to the Localize wrapper.
